# How to catch dataflow serialization errors in direct pipeline tests

Tags: serialization, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am working on implementing a set of DoFn and transforms in dataflow for some of which I need to use 3rd party libraries which are not serializable. 
I found a workaround to overcome the serialization issue for these with making the variable transient and initializing it lazily.
However, since my tests are running in direct pipeline (locally), I can only catch these cases if I run my pipeline on cloud. 
Is there any recommended way to test dataflow pipelines locally in order to catch these kinds of exceptions/errors?

Comment: Pipelines run using the DirectPipelineRunner will attempt to serialize/deserialize all data and functions used within the Pipeline. Are you disabling the serialization checks somehow? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DirectPipelineOptions.java#L48

Comment: No the parameters are not overwritten and from what i can see the default value seems to be true. But still we have cases where the serialization issues only show up in the DataflowRunner and not the DirectRunner.

Comment: Could you give more details about the serialization issue Direct runner failed to catch? It sounds like a bug that we should fix.